# Need Help modifying jquery.scrollto.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollto

I'm using this plug in (https://github.com/flesler/jquery.localScroll/blob/master/jquery.localScroll.js) to animate the vertical scroll on my site.

I need to remove 85 pixels from the scroll. So if the section is located on 1000, then i want the site to scroll to 915 instead.

I was using the scrollto plugin below. I was easily able to mod that one myself by adding the -85 to scrollTop, but the plugin only works with safari, which is why I decided to get a newer version of the scollto plugin. Now I have no idea how to modify the newer version. Can someone help me out?

Old version of Scrollto:

```
$.scrollTo = $.fn.scrollTo = function(x, y, options){
if (!(this instanceof $)) return $.fn.scrollTo.apply($('html, body'), arguments);

options = $.extend({}, {
    gap: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    animation: {
        easing: 'swing',
        duration: 600,
        complete: $.noop,
        step: $.noop
    }
}, options);

return this.each(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: !isNaN(Number(x)) ? x : $(y).offset().left + options.gap.x,
        scrollTop: !isNaN(Number(y)) ? y : $(y).offset().top + options.gap.y - 85
    }, options.animation);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since **[scrollto.js](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/blob/master/jquery.scrollTo.js)** has `offset` setting, you can easily set default offset without modifying the plugin.

```
$(function(){

    // set default offset to -85:
    $.scrollTo.defaults.offset = -85;

    //then call your localScroll:
    $("#your_elem").localScroll({
        // plugin options
    });

});
```